# Increasing volume beyond maximum with Logitech 430 7.1 Surround sound headphones

Tags: windows-7, audio, logitech-headset

I recently bought a pair of [Logitech](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/product/g430-7-1-surround-sound-gaming-headset) headphones with surround sound capabilities. They plug in through USB and have their own software. I noticed the software even at it's highest volume levels is pretty quiet. I've tried messing with Windows and everything, reading up on Windows problems, apparently Windows 7 doesn't output nearly as much sound as other operating systems. I wouldn't know because Windows 7 is all I use, just reading this [from a page](https://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/5505-volume-not-loud-enough-how-do-i-bypass-volume-limit-2.html#post805251). However, I also seen a lot of people were using on board sound and other things that could easily be fixed by a pair of decent headphones. I got these headphones expecting some high-quality sound and sound loud enough to actually be able to hear hard songs like DnB. The sound quality is high, but the sound itself is very low. A lot lower than I expected. I'm tired of continuously swapping headphones to try to find ones that sound great with Windows default sound, however I've haven't been able to find one leading me to believe it's something to do with Windows itself. Is there any way to completely pass the maximum volume of Windows or the Logitech software for my headphones?

My computer setup:
CPU: AMD FX-8320 - 3.5GHz 8 Cores
Hard drive: Western Digital Blue - 500GB 7200RPM
2nd Hard drive: Western Digital Blue - 500GB (IDE > Sata Connection)
Video card: EVGA GTX 1060 - 3G GDDR5 Memory
Power supply: EVGA - 500W
Mother board: MSI 970A-G43 - 32GB Max. RAM
RAM: Corsair Vengeance Pro - 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3-2400
Internet Adapter: TP-Link TL-WDN4800 - 450Mbit/s transfer

Comment: Never heard of such issue in a MSI 970A-G43 (but I never used Seven with it so you may have stumbled with something specific). Have you tried to install updated drivers provided by the manufacturer already?

Comment: Drivers for headphones are the latest, I'm out in the middle of no where, my highest connection speed to google is less than a megabyte connection. Downloading that is long but possible, I'll see about it.

Comment: I installed USB 3.0 drivers, they don't seem to make much of a difference. There is on board sound drivers, I don't know if they'll work since I'm using the logitech software already.

Comment: No, onboard audio, HDMI audio and USB audio are all different audio devices each one depending on specific drivers and work independently.

Comment: That's what I thought.

Comment: @MichaelBay I unplugged the headphones from USB and plugged them into my TV which is using HDMI. I actually think my head is going to explode they're that loud. Only problem is the quality took a crap because of crappy stereo drivers. I'm using the NVIDIA HDMI audio, it notices the TV is only stereo, is there any way to tell it to do surround sound?